# Setting up Elastic Enterprise Search and App Search - Docker - ELK

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, github, kibana, elk

I'm trying to setup Elastic Enterprise Search and App Search using Docker. So far I managed to install Elastic Search and Kibana using Docker on Centos 7. Right now, I want to establish a connection with GitHub, for which I'll need Enterprise search. I opened the page, but it's prompting to "Add your workspace Search host URL to your Kibana Configuration - enterpriseSearch.host: 'http://localhost:3002'
I didn't quite understand on how to do that. I'm stuck with this. Can anyone please provide some step-by-step instructions?

Answer (score 0):

As per the ElasticSearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html):

```
enterpriseSearch.host | The URL of your Enterprise Search instance
```

Comment: How do I find config/kibana.yml file?

Comment: Documentation again: 
KBN_PATH_CONF=/home/kibana/config ./bin/kibana

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at this step as well, to configure the kibana docker container you can either pass environment variables to the docker container as you run it (usually by making use of a docker-compose.yml file), or you can pass it a kibana.yml file on the command line.

Reference:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/docker.html#configuring-kibana-docker

It's worth noting if you are running elasticsearch on docker following the same instructions as me you have not opened up port 3002 when launching that which may need to be completed by changing the run code to include 3002:3002.